# Firefox not firing javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

---------SOLVED-----------
I have a javascript function:

```
  function getUserData(var1)
    {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "getData.php",
           data: "userId="+var1,
           success: function(msg){
              $('#contactForm').html(msg).show(1000);
           }
        });
   }
```

which is called by this link:

`<li id='test00' name='test00'><a href='#' onClick="getUserData('test00')">123 123</a></li>`

in chrome,safari works perfectly fine.  firefox, I do not get anything.  not even the page request in /var/log/httpd/access_log

for the simple sake of testing i tried.

```
function getUserData(var1)
{
   alert('hello');
}
```

and even that fails in firefox... any thoughts? what other things would you need to see to help.

i see no errors at all in firebug, java console......

it may be something larger...

even this fails:

ok, it may be something larger then the function itself.  even this failed

```
function getUserData()
{
alert('hello'); 
}
</script>
<a href='#' onclick="getUserData();">hello</a>
```

---------SOLVED-----------

I really wish I could say how this works.  but through the response, i decided to try a different function name

in jsFiddle this worked:

```
<li id='test00' name='test00'><a onClick="myFunction('test00')">123 123</a></li>
function myFunction(var1)
{
alert(var1);
}
```

this failed:

```
<li id='test00' name='test00'><a onClick="getUserData('test00')">123 123</a></li>
function getUserData(var1)
{
alert(var1);
}
```

no idea why!  but thank you everyone for the quick responses.....

Comment: can you get the function work using shift+f4 firefox js ?

Comment: shift+f4 js?  ..........

Comment: click shift +f4 in firefox
 enter getUserData() 
run it
 see if alert fires off

Comment: getUserData returns user data on a node in FireFox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.getUserData

Comment: bah, Thanks for the info Dave.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if you have JavaScript enabled in firefox :

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages#w_enabling-and-disabling-javascript

Comment: javascript is in fact enabled, all options enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `javascript` is `enabled` or not

Or try this:

**Javascript:**

```
function getUserData(var1)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getData.php",
       data: "userId="+var1,
       success: function(msg){
         $('#contactForm').html(msg).show(1000);
       }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.getUserDataClass').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        getUserData($(this).parent('li').attr('name'));
    });    
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li id='test00' name='test00'><a href='#' class="getUserDataClass">123 123</a></li>
```

Comment: this broke chrome and no change in ff.

Comment: Did you enable `javascript` in `ff`, also check have you added the `jquery` in your page?

Comment: this is what i have above the <script><!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/superfish.css" media="screen">
<link href="css/portalStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>

Comment: how do i press enter in these comment :) ?

Comment: Use `enter` key with `shift` :)

Comment: This is not the problem, if this creates any problem then `chrome` will not run that page.Problem is in your `ff`. Create a single page with a `button` and set `onclick="alert('test');"` then check by creating a `function`on that page.

Comment: Rohan,  I have <a href='#' onclick="getUserData();">hello</a> where getUserData is a function getUserData{alert('hello');}
which fails.   i have <a href='#' onclick="alert('hi');">hello</a>
 and that fires the alert....

Answer (score 0):

Firefox sometimes wants a return value. Try adding a `return false` your functions.

```
function getUserData(var1)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getData.php",
       data: "userId="+var1,
       success: function(msg){
$('#contactForm').html(msg).show(1000);
   }
 });
 return false;
}


function getUserData(var1)
{
alert('hello');
return false;
}
```